# What android widget is this?

Tags: android

does anybody know what android widget/view this is:

[image]

i want to be able to implement a similar widget for my own needs but i dont know what kind of view/widget it is. All i see is that it is embeded on the ContactContract class as a quickContact object.

Anyone used one of these and customized it? if so, how? Thanks in advance

edit: is it also possible to include more than 5 items as shown below and have it scrollable horizontaly

Answer (score 6):

This is QuickAction. [Here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) you can find implementation of it. And there is [repository on Github](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction) with source code.

Comment: Actual src code contains layouts, drawable files and values that some clash with my own project. i kind of thought the example above is just a lib i can use and plugin on my app but it is actually an android application rather then a lib i can use

Comment: edit: tried copying and pasting everthing in the src folder and res folder and now it messed up my android app as i cannot be built and compiled due to errors reporting that my R.class cannot be resolved :( looks like i will need another solution to this as the above code as stated, is a android app itself and combining it with another 9/10 causes issues with your own app. is there not a lib version of this project with just the src code?

Comment: You may edit source code and remove clashes, for example rename conflicting files in resources.

Comment: Ok mate i will try and give it another go. i tried to remove some classes etc but it ended up messing up my R.class file completely. what if i open the projetc in eclipse and just point to that project in my classpath. would that work? at least both projects will be seperated and wont clash with eachother. Not sure if thats doable with two android projects though. perfectly doable with a normal java project and android project

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but it seems a custom toast

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: No, it isn't toast. Toasts can't contains clickable elements.